# select query gives result where ID (a number) is equal to text

Tags: mysql, sql, type-conversion

I have a table `_users` with a field `id` as `bigint(24)`.

The result of this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `_users` WHERE `id`='5text'
```

is the row with `id = 5`. I would expect no result since *'5text'* is not a number. How is this possible?

Comment: What are you trying to say?Please eloborate some more.

Comment: I understand how this can be an issue, since it can return valid rows that have nothing to do with the queried id

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL implicitly converts strings to numbers when evaluates expressions to make the operands compatible.

From the documentation:

> If one of the arguments is a decimal value, comparison depends on the other argument. The arguments are compared as decimal values if the other argument is a decimal or integer value, or as floating-point values if the other argument is a floating-point value.

See the [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html)
 article for the detailed explanation and examples.